# Webpack Importing a javscript function from a module also imports every other statements and functions in that module

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am using webpack for my project.

Suppose I have a `dep.js` file which has the following code

```
export function abc() {
   var a = 10;
}

console.log(100);

function xyz(){
   var b = 11;
}

xyx();
```

And I have a `main.js` file which has the following code

```
import {abc} from './dep.js';
```

According to the logic of import and export, only the function `abc` should be imported.
But when i check the source in console i found that

--> all the other statement and function like `console.log(100)`, `function xyx` also got imported

--> and the effect of calling the function via `xyz()` in `dep.js` also shows the effect in `main.js`

Why this is happening?

Comment: Sometimes, you can increase the [pass option](https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/249#issuecomment-466672438) to increase tree shaking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's how modules work, by default. If any part of the module is imported at least once, the *whole module* runs all of its top level code.

It's possible to remove dead code that doesn't get run with [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) in Webpack, but the module shown doesn't have any dead code - it has an exported function, which gets used, and it has code which is run on the top level and called (the `console.log`, the declaration of `xyx`, and the call of `xyx`).

If you exported something which *wasn't* used elsewhere in the module, it could be dropped with tree shaking, eg:

```
export function abc(){
   var a = 10;
}
export function def(){
   var a = 10;
}
```

Here, if `def` is not imported or used elsewhere, it could be automatically removed.

(Also note that function definitions require `()`s after them, even if they take no arguments)

---

This sort of thing is why I almost always export *functions only* - it's good to avoid writing code that has side-effects on the top level of a module, because then just importing the module will result in those side-effects (like you're seeing here). It's generally easier to structure code when you have a single entry point (eg `main.js`) which imports the functions it needs and then calls them. If every module runs code with side-effects as part of the top level, things can quickly become very confusing and unmanageable. (This technique also happens to improve tree shaking, but that's just a side benefit)

Comment: Well said. Hey, do you think, in [my example](https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/249), if I were to *export* `let createCounterFunction`, the tree shaking would be more likely to occur?

Comment: the absence of `()` in `abc` was a typo. Thanks for letting me understand this point. There is one more thing. Suppose if i want to import a function `abc()` in `main.js` from `dependency.js` and expect it to execute `abc()` without manually executing in `main.js` after importing, should i execute function `abc` via `abc()` in `dependency.js` as it will run all top level code as u said? or is there any better way?

Comment: @LonnieBest I know only the basics of how tree-shaking works, but I'm not experienced with it or with its mechanics, sorry - no idea

Comment: @Jake If you *want* a module which has side-effects when imported (and doesn't have to be called), you can do so - think of the `dep.js` in your question, except without the `abc` function - rather, just use `import 'dep.js';`. It *can* work, but I wouldn't do it often, since it'll make control flow more opaque and make refactoring harder down the line. (Whether you put it into a function and then execute that function, or just put all the code on the top level, won't make a difference if you're trying to get the code to run without the importer explicitly calling a function)

Comment: @Jake : When I want to make sure that a function is omitted, when it is not used, I put that function in it own file (by itself). This always works; it is omitted every time it isn't imported.

Comment: @LonnieBest yeah that sounds convenient

Comment: @Jake Well, I wouldn't call it convenient, but it is dependable.