# Why nodejs runs other js file first before index.js file?

Tags: node.js

I have created a simple nodejs project to see how nodejs runtime execution flow works. In my project folder I have initiated a nodejs project with `npm init -y` command. Then added `"type": "module"` to the package.json file. After that I have created two files

**index.js** with following content

```
console.log("index.js")
import x from './test.js'
```

**test.js** with following content

```
console.log("test.js")
export default {}
```

When I tried to execute the index.js file with `node index.js` I got the result as follows

```
test.js
index.js
```

But I expected the otherway around. Could someone explain why this is the behavior I am getting. Also please advice me, is there any way to enforce nodejs to go through the index.js file first before the other one?

Comment: [Import statements are always hoisted to the very top of a module.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67513536/316310). You can use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) (which is not the same as the static import statement) to load modules at any time, eg `my_code(); await import('./foo.js');`.